# Error "You are now managing the runtime"

Tags: ibm-cloud

When I click on the bug in Bluemix Live Edit mode I get the error :

You are now managing the runtime (process) of your app. To manage your project, visit your [app dashboard](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/).

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error but an information note.

https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/livesync/#live_edit

When you clicked the bug, you are at an area where you can debug the Node.js runtime of your application.

The information note is simply letting you know that if you want to manage your project (e.g. your Bluemix services, logs, monitoring, routing, etc.), you should visit the application dashboard.

Comment: ic, I think this information belongs to a page, which also contains the buttons "Open Shell" , "Open Debugger", "Suspend", "Restart" and the app status. For some reason only the information note at the top was displayed. I tried it out this morning, the buttons and the status are there again.